# Python - Floating Bar Chart with y axis set at 0

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a floating bar chart with Python but unfortunately, I can't fix my y-axis at 0. It always starts from the lowest value of the bottom column (e.g. 1 in the code)

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Sw6.png)

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    objects = ('E', 'S' ,'G')
    y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
    performance = [10,8,6]
    
    plt.bar(y_pos, performance, bottom=(1,2,3), align='center')
    plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
    plt.ylabel('Values')
    plt.title('ESG scores')
    
    plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.ylim....`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by BigBen

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('E', 'S' ,'G')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
x = np.array([0,1,2])
performance = [10,8,6]

plt.bar(y_pos, performance, bottom=(1,2,3), align='center')
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylim(0) #<-----
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.title('ESG scores')
    
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the sollution you have to fix the value of `y axis` using `plt.yticks()`

Here is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
objects = ('E', 'S' ,'G')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
x = np.array([0,1,2])
performance = [10,8,6]
plt.bar(y_pos, performance, bottom=(1,2,3), align='center')
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.yticks(x)
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.title('ESG scores')
    
plt.show()
```

**OUTPUT**

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cetnK.jpg)

Comment: But it is giving the output

Comment: Thanks, Ujjwal Dash, works like a charm! Wish you a great weekend!

Comment: @BigBen do you a valid alternative to propose?

Comment: Using [`ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html).

Comment: Yeah :) That indeed works better. Thanks to both of you for the help! Gold medal for BigBen